# Bars 32-37 in Moonlight sonata first movement

Tags: piano, practice, memorization

I am having trouble playing and memorizing the broken chords sequence:

[image]

Should I try and practice on each triplet individually? because when I try to think on it as a broken chord I often can not play it correctly. Any other tips will be welcomed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a number of great ways to practice any given pattern. Taking the [rhythmic skeleton](https://secure.flickr.com/photos/jordanrandallsmith/8595271695/in/photostream) of your passage, you can apply 3 [different](https://secure.flickr.com/photos/jordanrandallsmith/8595271867/in/photostream) [Duple-based](https://secure.flickr.com/photos/jordanrandallsmith/8596372724/in/photostream) [patterns](https://secure.flickr.com/photos/jordanrandallsmith/8595272015/in/photostream), each with two 16ths and an 8th. Modifying the rhythm of each triplet thusly helps to develop 3 overlapping schema for each possible way to group 3 notes. Note, it's better to think of these, not as three different rhythm patterns but as three different starting points for a rapid group of 3 notes.

The obvious thing to do next would be to add more notes.

[image: Groupings]

In this case, you'll want to start to overlap, practicing the first triplet plus 2nd downbeat, then the 2nd triplet plus 3rd downbeat, and so on. This would continue on to [5 notes](https://secure.flickr.com/photos/jordanrandallsmith/8595272147/in/photostream), [6 notes](https://secure.flickr.com/photos/jordanrandallsmith/8596373110/in/photostream), and finally [7 notes](https://secure.flickr.com/photos/jordanrandallsmith/8595272287/in/photostream), which would constitute two full triplets plus the following downbeat.

**Diads, Triads**

There are dozens of other ways to practice, but here is one more valuable way to approach your particular example.

Although the fingerings may not match, it is valuable to ["flatten"](https://secure.flickr.com/photos/jordanrandallsmith/8596373176/in/photostream) each beat into a triad.

[image: Triads]

However, these particular arpeggiations are grouped into [diads](https://secure.flickr.com/photos/jordanrandallsmith/8596373310/in/photostream), so it's most helpful to flatten and organize them in that way.

Does this give you a few ideas to work with in this passage? I mocked these up quickly on my iPad so please forgive the incorrect enharmonic spellings used.

If you like my answer, I hope you'll accept it and up vote it. If you use [Flickr](http://flickr.com/jordanrandallsmith) at all, I hope you'll favorite one or two of my examples and add me as a contact. [I](http://www.jordanrsmith.com) look forward to your feedback!

Comment: wow, thank you for this great and elaborate answer. Your advice about flatting into diads is very helpful:) (I can even use the same fingering)

Comment: thanks for your feedback! I hope you'll connect with me on fb, twitter, or any other services you might use, links to them are on my profile. I like this site as it is helping me to meet and connect with thoughtful musicians like yourself and I hope to stay in touch with them beyond just one question on stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to write out the song using numbers instead of the chord letters. Eg using 1 for the chord based on the first note of the key and up to 7 for the last note. I actually recommend using roman numerals as they look better than numbers.

1 = I
2 = II

etc

that way you will much better be able to see what is going on with the chords changes